# JFace Wizard hiding and displaying button bar

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am new to JFace Wizard development, so forgive me if my question sounds weird.

I have requirement where my first `WizardPage` should not display button bar, This I have achieved by extending `WizardDialog` and implementing `createButtonsForButtonBar()` method.

Now second wizardpage will load when user do some action on first page(Click button on page). This second wizard page should have button bar. I am not able to show the button bar on second page. I tried exploring JFace code but couldn't find any way to do it.

Can someone confirm whether it is possible or not? If yes, Can you give me some pointers to do it?

Thanks in Advance for you time.

Comment: It might help to show what you have tried

Comment: I was able to do it using getButtonBar.setVisible() method in WizardDialog extended class.

Comment: It is very unusual to hide the button bar, normally you just use setPageComplete(false) to disable the Next / Finish buttons until the page is ready to move to the next page.

Comment: What do you do in `createButtonsForButtonBar()` to prevent the buttons from showing up?